# alert attribute from css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to alert an attribute of div element. but it alerted me `""` or `NULL`

here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-div"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
#my-div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
alert(document.getElementById("my-div").style.backgroundColor) 
//return ""
```

when I try this JS code it returns `""`

**JavaScript_2**:

```
alert(document.getElementById("my-div").getAttribute("background-color"))
//return NULL
```

and when I try this JS code it returns `NULL`

what should I do?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+css+property+is+empty) of [How to retrieve the display property of a DOM element?](/q/3778335/4642212).

Comment: You might also want to get familiar with [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) or [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(myDiv, null).getPropertyValue("background-color"))
```

```css
#my-div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Use this to get the color as name:

```js
const colorList = {
  aliceblue: "#F0F8FF",
  antiquewhite: "#FAEBD7",
  aqua: "#00FFFF",
  aquamarine: "#7FFFD4",
  azure: "#F0FFFF",
  beige: "#F5F5DC",
  bisque: "#FFE4C4",
  black: "#000000",
  blanchedalmond: "#FFEBCD",
  blue: "#0000FF",
  blueviolet: "#8A2BE2",
  brown: "#A52A2A",
  burlywood: "#DEB887",
  cadetblue: "#5F9EA0",
  chartreuse: "#7FFF00",
  chocolate: "#D2691E",
  coral: "#FF7F50",
  cornflowerblue: "#6495ED",
  cornsilk: "#FFF8DC",
  crimson: "#DC143C",
  cyan: "#00FFFF",
  darkblue: "#00008B",
  darkcyan: "#008B8B",
  darkgoldenrod: "#B8860B",
  darkgray: "#A9A9A9",
  darkgrey: "#A9A9A9",
  darkgreen: "#006400",
  darkkhaki: "#BDB76B",
  darkmagenta: "#8B008B",
  darkolivegreen: "#556B2F",
  darkorange: "#FF8C00",
  darkorchid: "#9932CC",
  darkred: "#8B0000",
  darksalmon: "#E9967A",
  darkseagreen: "#8FBC8F",
  darkslateblue: "#483D8B",
  darkslategray: "#2F4F4F",
  darkslategrey: "#2F4F4F",
  darkturquoise: "#00CED1",
  darkviolet: "#9400D3",
  deeppink: "#FF1493",
  deepskyblue: "#00BFFF",
  dimgray: "#696969",
  dimgrey: "#696969",
  dodgerblue: "#1E90FF",
  firebrick: "#B22222",
  floralwhite: "#FFFAF0",
  forestgreen: "#228B22",
  fuchsia: "#FF00FF",
  gainsboro: "#DCDCDC",
  ghostwhite: "#F8F8FF",
  gold: "#FFD700",
  goldenrod: "#DAA520",
  gray: "#808080",
  grey: "#808080",
  green: "#008000",
  greenyellow: "#ADFF2F",
  honeydew: "#F0FFF0",
  hotpink: "#FF69B4",
  indianred: "#CD5C5C",
  indigo: "#4B0082",
  ivory: "#FFFFF0",
  khaki: "#F0E68C",
  lavender: "#E6E6FA",
  lavenderblush: "#FFF0F5",
  lawngreen: "#7CFC00",
  lemonchiffon: "#FFFACD",
  lightblue: "#ADD8E6",
  lightcoral: "#F08080",
  lightcyan: "#E0FFFF",
  lightgoldenrodyellow: "#FAFAD2",
  lightgray: "#D3D3D3",
  lightgrey: "#D3D3D3",
  lightgreen: "#90EE90",
  lightpink: "#FFB6C1",
  lightsalmon: "#FFA07A",
  lightseagreen: "#20B2AA",
  lightskyblue: "#87CEFA",
  lightslategray: "#778899",
  lightslategrey: "#778899",
  lightsteelblue: "#B0C4DE",
  lightyellow: "#FFFFE0",
  lime: "#00FF00",
  limegreen: "#32CD32",
  linen: "#FAF0E6",
  magenta: "#FF00FF",
  maroon: "#800000",
  mediumaquamarine: "#66CDAA",
  mediumblue: "#0000CD",
  mediumorchid: "#BA55D3",
  mediumpurple: "#9370DB",
  mediumseagreen: "#3CB371",
  mediumslateblue: "#7B68EE",
  mediumspringgreen: "#00FA9A",
  mediumturquoise: "#48D1CC",
  mediumvioletred: "#C71585",
  midnightblue: "#191970",
  mintcream: "#F5FFFA",
  mistyrose: "#FFE4E1",
  moccasin: "#FFE4B5",
  navajowhite: "#FFDEAD",
  navy: "#000080",
  oldlace: "#FDF5E6",
  olive: "#808000",
  olivedrab: "#6B8E23",
  orange: "#FFA500",
  orangered: "#FF4500",
  orchid: "#DA70D6",
  palegoldenrod: "#EEE8AA",
  palegreen: "#98FB98",
  paleturquoise: "#AFEEEE",
  palevioletred: "#DB7093",
  papayawhip: "#FFEFD5",
  peachpuff: "#FFDAB9",
  peru: "#CD853F",
  pink: "#FFC0CB",
  plum: "#DDA0DD",
  powderblue: "#B0E0E6",
  purple: "#800080",
  rebeccapurple: "#663399",
  red: "#FF0000",
  rosybrown: "#BC8F8F",
  royalblue: "#4169E1",
  saddlebrown: "#8B4513",
  salmon: "#FA8072",
  sandybrown: "#F4A460",
  seagreen: "#2E8B57",
  seashell: "#FFF5EE",
  sienna: "#A0522D",
  silver: "#C0C0C0",
  skyblue: "#87CEEB",
  slateblue: "#6A5ACD",
  slategray: "#708090",
  slategrey: "#708090",
  snow: "#FFFAFA",
  springgreen: "#00FF7F",
  steelblue: "#4682B4",
  tan: "#D2B48C",
  teal: "#008080",
  thistle: "#D8BFD8",
  tomato: "#FF6347",
  turquoise: "#40E0D0",
  violet: "#EE82EE",
  wheat: "#F5DEB3",
  white: "#FFFFFF",
  whitesmoke: "#F5F5F5",
  yellow: "#FFFF00",
  yellowgreen: "#9ACD32",
};

const toColor = (color) => {
  const [r, g, b] = color.replace("rgb(", "").replace(")", "").split(", ").map(parseFloat)
  const hex = "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1).toUpperCase();
  return Object.keys(colorList).filter(e => colorList[e] === hex)?.pop() ?? hex;
}

const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-div");
console.log(toColor(window.getComputedStyle(myDiv, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")))
```

```css
#my-div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-div">test</div>
```